# How To Get Wifi Password With Connecting via ethernet cable

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, noobs, password

I just got the raspberry pi 3 and i wanna know if its possible to get the wifi password via connecting with a ethernet cable

p.s. its noobs 2.4.2

p.p.s. sorry if its a dumb question i am a beginner

Comment: What do you mean by get the WiFi password? Get the password needed by your router to connect to it? Retrieve the one you used to connect to your router?

Comment: my router doesn't have any sticker or anything that tells me my password but when i connect my raspi to it via ethernet cable it gives me internet access so i just wanted to know if  i can figure out the wifi password through the information im getting from the ethernet wire

Comment: Please edit your question and add those details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Pi does not have a WiFi connection. It does not know the password needed to connect to your router.

There are a few things you can try:

- Contact your ISP,
- Search the internet for the default password (some devices come with a default password),
- You could try hacking the password (using Kali Linux - this can even be done with the Pi),
- Check other devices for the password (like your phone or tablet),
- You may be able to login to the router and determine or reset the WiFi password.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is this?
"my router doesn't have any sticker or anything that tells me my password"

what you CAN do is **log into your router's web interface** and
a) view the current wifi settings including password or if not visible then
b) reset the password.

This involves knowing the router's IP address, which is also the "gateway" IP address (usually.)  it might be 192.168.1.1 or 10.0.0.1 perhaps.  This will get you started old bean!
The login details are often name: admin password: admin